# Midnight Commander - Is there a way of customize it's keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: configuration, mc

Is there a text file that Midnight Commander reads for its hotkeys/shortcuts or are they hard-coded into the app?

Comment: In general, whenever you have a question about a *NIX program's command line, config files, etc. the first thing to check should be `man <command>` or `info <command>`.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 18.04 the folder with configuration files is located: `~/.config/mc`

To customize the keyboard shortcuts You need to copy the default file from the `/etc/mc` folder into `~/.config/mc`:

```
cp /etc/mc/mc.keymap ~/.config/mc/
```

Look inside that file and adjust it as needed.

Comment: Not only on Ubuntu :)